# 000webhostapp .htaccess error after editing

Tags: html, .htaccess, web, password-protection, internal-server-error

i'm currently using a free account at 000webhostapp.com, when i open the file manager it already had a .htaccess file, i'm trying to make my index.html password protected with .htpasswd and .htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /public_html/tristan.htpasswd
Require valid-user

<Files "index.html">Require valid-user</Files>
```

but it already had a file in it that cannot be edited

```
# HTID:4294076: DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW
php_value display_errors 1
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE HTID:4294076:
```

and when i try to put the first code under it

[(im still not popular enough, so click here to view the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYGty.png)

it errors out

[click to view the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx0nx.png)

i have googled it for hours and i can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

`Require` directive can not be in the same line as `<files>` otherwise you get a syntax error. So place it in a new line.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /public_html/tristan.htpasswd
Require valid-user
<Files "index.html">
Require valid-user
</Files>
```